Tesseract4 Namespace not in iText Nuget Package?
I have the following NuGet Packages in my .NET Core 8 console app:

When I try to use the example on the iText website to OCR a PDF I get an error with one of the using statements:

When I look in the Namespace I do not see Tesseract4. Am I missing a NuGet package? This seems like I am missing something simple, yet I have spent way too much time trying to figure it out.
Thanks

@KJ same for me... The example doesn't compile on the website or in a console app. The namespace is missing for some reason
